# How to save files in a different location after conversion with FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFMpeg on Windows to add the same audio to multiple videos using the following line of code:

```
for %i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -y -i "%i" -i m.mp3 -af apad -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest "%~ni with audio.mp4"
```

The problem is that the program saves the output files in the same location. Is there any way that I can save them in another location?

Answer (score 0):

you can tell FFmpeg to output to a folder like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 path\to\some\folder\output.mp4
```